# Importing data from CSV into Talend and convert to output to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, talend

Dears,

I need to build the following program in low code and I have no clue where to find the correct blocks in order to create the flow. Unfortunately within the time limit given, I can't start an entire course to learn the program inside out, so I'm just searching for parts or search terms so I can read the official correct documentation covering these actions. Up to now I am quite lost in the documentation what to look for. I don't need anyone to build it for me, I need to understand how to build it myself.

**I've got the following files;**

- Alpha.csv + Beta.csv

- Alpha contains 6 columns. Column02 contains either int "1" or "2".
  And column06 contains a 6 digit number.
- Beta.csv contains 2 columns. Where column01 is a string and column02 is a 6 digit number (like
  column06 from Alpha.csv).

**The goal here is to:**

- import Alpha.csv, convert what needs to be convert and create an output to a PostgreSQL.

- Where the output needs to be one-on-one equal from Alpha.csv.

  - Except that Column02 needs to be changed from "1" to Apple and "2" to "Orange".
  - Column05 contains a number with sometimes a letter I.E. "112A". In the output only the number
    should be visible (hence remove "A" as per the example).
  - Column06 needs to change from int to a string. The 6 digit number has to be converted into
    the string from Beta.csv

So far I've got attached schedule. I've included both Alpha and Beta csv as a picture.

Any help would be very welcome!
If you have any direct links to steer me in the right direction I would be for ever in your debt (in figure of speech that is ;) ). All though the official terms / naming of what needs to be done would be very helpful as well, as I could search far more directly in the official documentation /  youtube video's explaining "how-to".

[Image of Talend-Job + Alpha.csv + Beta.csv[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zjJz.png)

Comment: Please add code as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

These are basic transformations that you need. First learn how to create a metadata using CSV. Then how to use tMap, which is the main component for transformations. As you need to connect to a postgresql database, also check how to declare a DB Connection and use it in talend.  For all talend components, if you press F1 you get access to the Talend Help Section for that component, containing quite clear examples.

Your question is a bit broad, so feel free to create other post with more precise questions once you have tried a bit more.